# What is the meaning of "A.C. or D.C.?"

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, literature

In Heinlein's *A stranger in a strange land*, there is a moment when nurse Jill kisses Martian man named Mike and another man, Jubal, puts a comment on it. It comes as follows:

> “Son,” he said, “you amaze me. I would have expected you to curl up in one of your faints.”
>
> “I so did,” Mike answered seriously, without letting go, “on first kissing time.”
>
> “Well! Congratulations, Jill. A.C., or D.C.?”
>
> “Jubal, you’re a tease but I love you anyhow and refuse to let you get my goat. Mike got a little upset once—but no longer, as you can see.”

The only meaning of AC and DC I found was alternating current and direct current, but it is about electric power distribution and is definitely not my case. I have no idea about meaning and genesis of Jubal's mockery. Can anyone, please, explain it to me?

Don't pay attention to Mike's strange language - he is the Man from Mars and has a different native language and way of thinking.

Comment: Are you sure you copied that all out quite right? “On first kissing time” is not what I would call English.

Comment: Maybe it is just a play between AC/DC and A.D. (anno domini) and B.C. (before Christ)?

Comment: Janus - your comment is weird (no offense!); the "on first-kissing time" phrase makes perfect sense. Note too he's a martian.

Comment: skyminge - there's uttelry no connection to "before christ" - it's a common way to refer to sexual orientation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In my youth (the 1960s and 1970s) AC/DC was a euphemism for bisexual.  As far as I recall AC meant heterosexual and DC meant homosexual (derived from Alternating current and Direct current) and I suspect that Heinlein is using it in this way as the book dates from that period.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is apparently a right translation and it suits Jubal as an old cynical man.

Comment: So the term is not currently used?

Comment: Hey PH!  IMHO, you're wrong that, in particular, "AC means one and DC means the other".  I don't think anyone's that specific about it, and can't see any references theretofore.  "AC/DC" (human sexuality meaning) is just a general rowdy reference to straight versus homosexual preferences.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's completely commonplace (today, 2014) to use "AC/DC" as a rowdy term to refer to the differences between homosexual and heterosexual. (Note that one of the top ten most famous rock bands of all times has this term as a name.)

Comment: @JoeBlow the derivation surely is that Alternating current is about opposites (hence hetero) and Direct current is same to same, (hence homo), but I agree that the phrase is always used together as AC/DC, meaning swings both ways.

Comment: PH. That's a great point!! I would just say: you'd struggle to find examples where people specifically unwind each one to the specific "side".  I feel, it is just used generally (as is, complete) to signify the rowdy difference. By all means bring examples and show them being used "individually" if you will.

Comment: Dictionaries define this as slang for BI and as a huge fan of Heinlein can attest that that is what he meant. [ac/dc](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ac-dc)

Comment: Well the quote from the book is "A.C., or D.C.?" rather than "AC/DC".

Comment: JoeBlow, this is definitely dated at least in all parts of America I've been to (NYC, DC, LA).  I'm active in the LGBT community and the only times I've ever heard this were in this book and The Talisman by Stephen King.  I would not expect your average person to definitely understand it--maybe there's a generation gap?

Comment: It's archaic slang from the 50's and 60's.  Still heard it some in the 70's, but hardly ever after that.

Comment: The trouble with the "heterosexual or homosexual" interpretation of "A.C. or D.C?" is that it makes no sense in the context of the passage. Jill is female, Mike is male; why would Jubal ask "straight or gay" in response to their kiss?

Comment: HI @thumbtackthief !  I am truly interested to hear that "ac/dc" is - basically - **out of date!** as a general sort of snicker term to refer to issues regarding homo- or bi- sexuality.  It makes perfect sense now that you say it. I am boringly "straight" (is that a dated term now! heh) so obviously it's a case of talking out one's ass when not an expert. I guess it's been decades since i lived in the village. Thanks for that!

Comment: There’s a notable use in the [Sweet song “AC/DC”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desolation_Boulevard) which has been covered by Joan Jett in 2006 and Vince Neil in 2010.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Maybe we need more context?

Comment: @NateEldredge More context here; after several reads of the book over many years, I remain baffled. http://books.google.com/books?id=jBtDSf1VzQkC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172

Comment: Is it established that Mike, is, in fact male, or is there a possibility that he is not clearly gendered to a human and Jill was free to interpret him as male or female at the time of the kiss?  The question is to her.  So if Jubal knows she is a closet bisexual lesbian (which I have seen Heinlein assume of all women, sometimes) it could be an in-joke between them.

Comment: @Russell: Heinlein also uses the phrase in *I Will Fear No Evil* (1970) where it very clearly has this meaning, so it's very likely that it means the same in *Stranger in a Strange Land* (1961), even though the actual use is a bit mysterious. Possibly Jubal is asking Jill for her opinion as to Mike's sexual orientation as revealed by the kiss. (In the next paragraph Mike offers to kiss Jubal.)

Comment: @JonJayObermark, Mike is clearly gendered as male throughout the book.

Comment: @GarethRees, that's possible, but it seems a stretch, since Jubal has immediately prior to this given Mike an "A for effort" on a heterosexual kiss.

Comment: Sorry, that is right Mike is human.  The question is whether that is taken to be obvious to Jill on first meeting.

Comment: @JonJayObermark: That's a good theory, but it's mentioned later in the book that Jill does *not* have "Lesbian tendencies". I don't know if Jubal might assume that she does, but I don't think it can be an in-joke between them.

Comment: Since, as Russel observed correctly, sexual orientation is not in question here, it may be that Jubal is joking whether the cause of Mike's curling up was an electric shock delivered by Jill's kiss.

Answer (score 2):

AC/DC refers to the two main types of electric power.

However, it's used humorously to mean "straight" versus "homosexual" sexual orientation.

It's that simple.

(Note that one of the world's most famous rock bands, is called "AC/DC" ... as well as referring to "electricity," as in electric instruments, it's a sexually-charged term.)

Comment: perhaps someone could determine **the origin of this usage** or **when it was first used this way**.

Comment: FWIW, the OED gives the following definition of AC/DC: AC/DC abbreviation.
1 Alternating current/direct current.
2 Bisexual. slang.
Unfortunately it gives no date of first use (or derivation) for the slang version.

Comment: However, I also found this on dictionary.com:

AC/DC 

"bisexual," 1959, said to have been in use orally from c.1940, from electronics abbreviation of alternating current/direct current. 

Online Etymology Dictionary, © 2010 Douglas Harper

(and elsewhere the idea that it means "accepts both types of current = both genders" which is rather neat)

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ac-dc

Answer (score -1):

There is an old children's joke involving an electric eel who is asked by a friend how his date with another eel went. He responded that they weren't dating anymore because she was A/C and he was D/C.

When there is a strong romantic chemistry, we sometimes encounter another idiom that "sparks fly" upon the first kiss. This is also a reference to electricity. However, sometimes the couple find just as quickly that, after having gone that far, they simply aren't interested in pursuing the relationship any further; thus, incompatible.

Since alternating current and direct current are two forms of electricity that are incompatible despite being equally powerful, the metaphor of A/C vs D/C can express that idea fairly well. It does not require nor exclude a further meaning involving sexual orientation.

Comment: Hello John. _What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer: one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case an encyclopedia, dictionary, or some other such document, showing this metaphorical usage). Edit your question and put in your support; then we'll be able to vote up your answer!_ [modified; after Matt Gutting]